# Fujitsu LifeBook A531 laptop touchpad scrolling

Tags: laptop, touchpad, scrolling

Is it possible to scroll using your touchpad on this laptop? All my older laptops let you scroll in some way but I must be missing something on my Fujitsu.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether the touchpad drivers are installed correctly and if necessary update them. Depending on the kind (and age) of your touchpad you might not be able to do a two-finger scroll but scrolling by using the edge of the touchpad should be possible.

You can grab the drivers here:

http://www.fujitsu-pc-asia.com/driversupport/selectioninterface/selection.html#

Answer (score 0):

Further to Ke Gu - it is probably only the edges of the pad used for scrolling. This from the [AH531 user manual](http://solutions.us.fujitsu.com/www/content/pdf/SupportGuides/AH531_UG_B6FJ-5551-02ENZ0-00_rA.pdf):

Scrolling Up/Down:
To scroll up or down, place your finger on the right side of the pad and move it forward or backward to 
scroll up or down.
Scrolling Right/Left:
To scroll right or left, place your finger on the bottom of the pad and move it right or left to scroll right or 
left.

It took me a while to work it out for my Sony! There are also other gestures described for continuous scrolling.